# C# HTML to PDF WkHtmlToPdf wrapper

Tags: c#

I am using C# HTML to PDF Wk HtmlToPdf wrapper
While trying to run the below code
An exception of type 'System Unauthorized Access Exception' occurred in ms cor lib but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path is denied.

Any suggestions and help on this please

Here is the code which i picked from http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: var htmlContent = String.Format("<body>Hello world: {0}</body>", 
  DateTime.Now);
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlContent);

Comment: Please adit it to your original question by using the `edit` button :)

Comment: trying to just work on thsi from the following link http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx

Comment: I'm guessing your path is wrong. What is your path where you try to save PDF?

Comment: I did not set any path as such but GeneratePdf(html) is picking up the project path C:\Digital\Latest\src\Solutions.Web\wkhtmltopdf.exe' is denied.

Answer (score 0):

I think the folder which contains 'wkhtmltopdf.exe' is not accessible to your application. Please try to run your application in Administrator mode. I think that might help you...